# Question mark button in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I make a messagebox appear when I click on the question mark button? I tried some code from posts, but it doesn't work.

Questionmark:

[image]

Comment: At the very least, you should show what "code from posts" you did try and what were the effects. We expect users to show that they did attempt to solve their problems on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QMessageBox is a commonly used modal dialog to display some informational message and optionally ask the user to respond by clicking any one of the standard buttons on it. Each standard button has a predefined caption, a role and returns a predefined hexadecimal number.

Important methods and enumerations associated with QMessageBox class are given in the following table −

```
S.No.        Methods & Description

setIcon()    Displays predefined icon corresponding to severity of the message

Question     Question

Information Information

Warning     Warning

Critical     Critical

setText()    Sets the text of the main message to be displayed

setInformativeText() Displays additional information

setDetailText()  Dialog shows a Details button. This text appears on clicking it

setTitle()  Displays the custom title of dialog


setStandardButtons()  List of standard buttons to be displayed. Each button is associated with

QMessageBox.Ok 0x00000400

QMessageBox.Open 0x00002000

QMessageBox.Save 0x00000800

QMessageBox.Cancel 0x00400000

QMessageBox.Close 0x00200000

QMessageBox.Yes 0x00004000

QMessageBox.No 0x00010000

QMessageBox.Abort 0x00040000

QMessageBox.Retry 0x00080000

QMessageBox.Ignore 0x00100000


setDefaultButton()  Sets the button as default. It emits the clicked signal if Enter is pressed

setEscapeButton()  Sets the button to be treated as clicked if the escape key is pressed
```

Straight from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qmessagebox.htm)

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

def window():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = QWidget()
   b = QPushButton(w)
   b.setText("Show message!")

  b.move(50,50)
   b.clicked.connect(showdialog)
   w.setWindowTitle("PyQt Dialog demo")
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

def showdialog():
   msg = QMessageBox()
  msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)

   msg.setText("This is a message box")
   msg.setInformativeText("This is additional     information")
   msg.setWindowTitle("MessageBox demo")
  msg.setDetailedText("The details are as follows:")
   msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | 
QMessageBox.Cancel)
   msg.buttonClicked.connect(msgbtn)

   retval = msg.exec_()
   print "value of pressed message box button:", retval

def msgbtn(i):
   print "Button pressed is:",i.text()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   window()
```

Comment: nice, btw how can i code this question mark: button ?:P

Comment: Added an example into my answer if that helps you!